# Displaying object at xy position defined in Ruby on Rails model

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, css

I am working on trying to pull the x and y position from a model in ruby on rails and represent it in html 5. The position has already been captured through jquery with a drag and drop, but I am not able to find any information on how to proceed.

To make it more clear.
I have an x-position and a y-position variable which are set.
I need to place an interactable image on a page at the location saved in the method.

Thanks and feel free to let me know if there is a way to be more clear.

EDIT::

This is the controller for the table model (very new to RoR),

```
class TablesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_table, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

  # GET /tables

  # GET /tables.json

  def index

    @tables = Table.all

  end



  # GET /tables/1

  # GET /tables/1.json

  def show

  end

  # GET /tables/new

  def new

    @table = Table.new

  end

  # GET /tables/1/edit

  def edit

  end

  # POST /tables

  # POST /tables.json

  def create

    @table = Table.new(table_params)

    respond_to do |format|

      if @table.save

        format.html { redirect_to @table, notice: 'Table was successfully 
created.' }

        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @table }

        format.js {render :json => @table}

      else

        format.html { render :new }

        format.json { render json: @table.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity 
}

        format.js {render :json =>@table.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}

      end

    end

  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tables/1

  # PATCH/PUT /tables/1.json

  def update

    respond_to do |format|

      if @table.update(table_params)

        format.html { redirect_to @table, notice: 'Table was successfully 
updated.' }

        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @table }

      else
        format.html { render :edit }

        format.json { render json: @table.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end

    end

  end

  # DELETE /tables/1
  # DELETE /tables/1.json

  def destroy

    @table.destroy

    respond_to do |format|

      format.html { redirect_to tables_url, notice: 'Table was successfully 
destroyed.' }

      format.json { head :no_content }

    end

  end

  private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    def set_table

      @table = Table.find(params[:id])

    end



    def table_params

      params.permit(:num_seats, :restaurant_id, :x_loc, :y_loc, :available)

    end

end
```

EDIT #2::

I have tried both using the variable for in-line css styling as suggested as well as  javascript making an HTML 5 canvas. The css styling is the only one pulling up the image for each iteration in an each do loop, but it is not positioning correctly.

I have debugging statements that are showing it is getting the info.

```
<script>document.write("<%=table.x_loc%>")</script>
```

gives the correct information, however,

`<img id = "pic" style = "left: <%=table.x_loc%>; top:<%=table.y_loc%>;" src="<%=asset_path( 'overheadtable.jpg')%>">`

is not positioning the image correctly.

Comment: can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: `<img style="left: <%= x %>; top: <%= y %>;">`

Comment: I added the controller code, as I think thats the best thing to show what I'm after, the table model is placed by a restaurant owner at will, a new one is created each time and x and y saved. I then want the customer on a new view to be able to look at the restaurant and see an image of where each table is located at (will need to loop).

Comment: And then hopefully be able to click on that image for an interactive pulldown

Comment: Is the containing element on display the same dimensions as the one used for the original drag and drop? Is the container set to `position: relative`? Is your `<img>` set to `position: absolute`?